# Recursive array manipulation for lexer/parser scoping of custom dsl

Tags: javascript

Trying to work out this algorithm. Having a hard time getting the indexes tweaked just right.

No this is **not** for a homework assignment. I'm pulling these rules from the docs of the library I'm creating.

The goal is to take an array of objects, then "scope" them, as in programmatically nest them logically (basically this is a part of the lexer/parser)

```
Rules: (`down === level++`) *down means the level has increased*
 - If the item is at the same level, move to the next item in the array
 - If the item is down a level, cut/paste all direct siblings at or below
   the current level onto the previous item and then recursively scope those
```

**Starting model:** *levels define how the dsl should be nested*

```
[
  {level: 0, dsl: {text: 'if'}},
  {level: 1, dsl: {text: 'test'}},
  {level: 0, dsl: {text: 'else'}},
  {level: 1, dsl: {text: 'prod'}},
  {level: 0, dsl: {text: 'end'}}
];
```

**Scoping function:** *current attempt*

```
function scope(items) {
  var currentLevel = items[0].level;
  var idx = 0;
  while (idx < items.length) {
    if (items[idx].level !== currentLevel) {
      var levels = items.map(function(x){return x.level;});
      var itemIdx = levels.indexOf(currentLevel, idx);
      items[idx - 1].dsl.scope = scope(items.splice(idx, itemIdx));
    } 
    idx++;
  }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  {text: 'if', scope: [{text: 'test'}]},
  {text: 'else', scope: [{text: 'prod'}]},
  {text: 'end'}
[
```

Currently I'm getting an error `can't read level of undefined` which is not necessarily important as placing some console logs in the scoping function shows that it's not selecting the right items in the array during the splice.

[Current fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dv07bph/)

**Question:** *for those who can't seem to grasp it from the above*

How do I correctly splice an array or objects, based on a property value, and inject that array into a property on the previous index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that I was mis-understanding the signature of the `splice` function. The signature is `splice(start, number)` instead of `splice(start, end)`

Working function is the same but with this correction. Converting the start and end indexes into a count of how many items match.

```
var numberToMove = itemIdx - idx;
items[idx - 1].dsl.scope = scope(items.splice(idx, numberToMove));
```